# Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException after adding JsonBackedReference

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test, jackson2

I created my spring-boot app, and added *JsonMangedReference* and *JsonBackReference* on my DTO object to ignore infinite recursion but now my test case is failing to say, I assumed it just ignored deserializing  JSON object on favorite DTO but this one is saying I am expecting JSON but it is not producing JSON

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<415>
Expected :200
Actual   :415
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at com.self.zoo.controller.AnimalControllerTest.addAnimal(AnimalControllerTest.java:65)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    <system-out><![CDATA[2022-05-25 12:00:20.996  WARN 444 --- [           main] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.self.zoo.dto.AnimalDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': no back reference property found from type `java.util.Set<com.self.zoo.entity.Favorite>`
2022-05-25 12:00:21.003  WARN 444 --- [           main] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.self.zoo.dto.AnimalDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': no back reference property found from type `java.util.Set<com.self.zoo.entity.Favorite>`
2022-05-25 12:00:21.008  WARN 444 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Below is my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AnimalController.class)
class AnimalControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    AnimalService animalService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws InvalidRoomDetailException {
        AnimalDto response = new AnimalDto();
        response.setId(1l);
        when(animalService.add(any())).thenReturn(response);
    }

    @Test
    void addAnimal() throws Exception {
        AnimalDto animalDto = createAnimalDtoObject();

        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                   .post("/animal/add")
                   .content(asJsonString(animalDto))
                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                   .andExpect(status().isOk())
                   .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").exists());

    }

    private AnimalDto createAnimalDtoObject() {
        AnimalDto animalDto = new AnimalDto();
        RoomDto roomDto = new RoomDto();
        roomDto.setSize(25l);
        roomDto.setTitle("Green");
        RoomDto roomDto1 = new RoomDto();
        roomDto1.setSize(10l);
        roomDto1.setTitle("Blue");
        animalDto.setRoom(roomDto);
        //animalDto.setFavoriteRooms();
        FavoriteDto f1 = new FavoriteDto();
        f1.setAnimalDto(animalDto);
        f1.setRoomDto(roomDto);
        FavoriteDto f2 = new FavoriteDto();
        f2.setAnimalDto(animalDto);
        f2.setRoomDto(roomDto1);
        Set<FavoriteDto> favSet = new HashSet<>();
        favSet.add(f2);
        favSet.add(f1);
        animalDto.setFavoriteRooms(favSet);
        return animalDto;
    }
}
```

below is my AnimalDto class

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnimalDto {
    Long id;
    String title;
    LocalDateTime located;
    String type;
    Long preference;
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<FavoriteDto> favoriteRooms;
    RoomDto room;

}
```

and my favoriteDTO

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FavoriteDto {

    RoomDto roomDto;
    @JsonBackReference
    AnimalDto animalDto;
    Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your classes appear to be correct.

try to put one

```
System.out.println(asJsonString(animalDto));
```

to see what input the test is sending to the API, to try to validate it is correct.