# Where to put JsonIgnore in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jackson2

Which is an ideal place to use `JsonView` or `JsonIgnore`? DTO or Entity layer? I have added it into the DTO layer but my ignored property is set to Null. and if I don't use I am stuck with infinite recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct one is for you to use it in the class you are returning, if you are returning the DTO, you must treat it, so that it does not return recursive data, you may need to remodel the class, as it is not very interesting to have infinitely recursive data.

if you still have doubts about what to do, if possible insert your code so that we can analyze it better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375057/type-org-springframework-web-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-after-adding-j here I already added my classes and this my repo https://github.com/vihang16/zooApplication